# Returning a pointer to a class within a class

Tags: c++, class, pointers, return

this is the first time I've done something like this so I'm a little uncertain how I need to do this. I have a very simple class which contains some simple values and some getters:

```
class Nucleotide{
    private:
        char Base;
        int Position;
        int Polymorphic;
    public:
        Nucleotide(char ch, int pos);
        int getPos();
        char getBase();
        int getPoly();
};
```

This class is present in another class that contains a vector of them:

```
class NucleotideSequence{
    private:
        std::string Name;
        std::vector<Nucleotide> Sequence;
    public:
        NucleotideSequence(std::string name, std::vector<Nucleotide> seq);
        std::string getName();
        Nucleotide getBase(int pos1);
};
```

I want the method of the second class called getBase to be able to take a integer - say 1, and return the first Nucleotide object in the vector. What I've written is below:

```
Nucleotide NucleotideSequence::getBase(int pos1)
{
    for(std::vector<Nucleotide>::iterator i = Sequence.begin(); i != Sequence.end(); i++)
    {
        if(pos1 == (*i).getPos())
        {
            return i; // Return a pointer to the correct base.
        }
    }
}
```

I've got Nucleotide as the return type but I was wondering really how I should change this - since if I return nucleotide because of pass by value would it not just return a copy of the object at that place in the vector? So I'd rather return a pointer/reference. I'm using an iterator in the loop so should I just return a pointer with the value of the iterator? How do I do this? In the function I return i but should I be returning i&? I'm uncertain about the specifics - presumably if I'm returning a pointer my return type needs to be Nucleotide* or perhaps Nucleotide& since & means address of? I've thought this through and read Cpp tuts but I'm still slightly unsure of the right answer.

Thanks,
Ben.

Comment: Can't you just use `Sequence[pos1]` in some way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to return the Nucleotide *by reference*:

```
Nucleotide & NucleotideSequence::getBase(int pos1)
{
    for(std::vector<Nucleotide>::iterator i = Sequence.begin(); i != Sequence.end(); i++)
    {
        if(pos1 == (*i).getPos())
        {
            return *i; // Notice the *i instead of i
        }
    }
}
```

A *reference* works very similarly to pointer (allows you to pass the actual object, not its copy), but cannot be null and cannot point to non-existing object, so it's a lot safer than pointer.

Note though, that if you don't find the desired `Nucleotide`, you don't return anything, what generally is not a good idea. In this case using pointers may actually be a better idea:

```
Nucleotide * NucleotideSequence::getBase(int pos1)
{
    for(std::vector<Nucleotide>::iterator i = Sequence.begin(); i != Sequence.end(); i++)
    {
        if(pos1 == (*i).getPos())
        {
            return &(*i); 
        }
    }

    return nullptr;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't return a pointer, you attempt to return the iterator. And the function is declared to return an instance and not a pointer. Also, if you don't find the `Nucleotide` you don't return anything at all leading to undefined behavior if you try to use the "returned" value.

You *could* change the function to return a pointer, or a reference, or just a by value (copying like it's declared like not.

You can also change so that the function takes the `Nucleotide` as an argument instead, and then return a boolean indicator if it was found or not.

```
bool NucleotideSequence::getBase(int pos1, Nucleotide& n)
{
    for (...)
    {
        if (...)
        {
            n = *i;
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;  // Not found
}
```

Comment: The downside of your soultion is that you actually need an existing Nucleotide to pass to this function. I thought of this solution and in this case having a C#-style `Nucleotyde::Empty` would be useful, but might complicate things.

Comment: @Spook Of course. The major downside with this is that it's not possible to chain the call (i.e. let the function be used as part of an expression). Though that is not recommended when returning a pointer so in that case I don't see much of a difference.

Answer (score 0):

As far as your question is concerned, returning a reference (&) as suggested by others is the solution.

In order to improve your code, I would as well suggest a change:

Either go for the operator[], or use the at() present in std::vector.

Thus, you can directly say:

**return Sequence[pos1];** or **return Sequence.at(pos1);**

Comment: This is more a comment than an answer, but a very correct one at that.

Comment: not quite, because the getPos() method does not correlate with the position of the Nucleotide in the sequence.

Comment: @CompuChip I am still not allowed to post comment to a question, hence had to post it here.

Comment: @SirDarius This statement in the question above proves my point, "I want the method of the second class called getBase to be able to take a integer - say 1, and return the first Nucleotide object in the vector."

Comment: @gargankit then the question contradicts itself, and should be clarified.

Answer (score 0):

Your code will benefit from some use of references for efficiency's sake.  The `getBase` method signature should look like this:

```
const Nucleotide& NucleotideSequence::getBase(int pos1)
```

The `NucleotideSequence` constructor signature should look like this:

```
NucleotideSequence(const std::string& name, const std::vector<Nucleotide>& seq);
```

And the `getName` method like this:

```
const std::string& getName();
```

(Although [return value optimisation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization) might make that less important.)

As for the contents of getBase, it might help understanding to break down the code into:

```
const Nucleotide* NucleotideSequence::getBase(int pos1)
{
    for(std::vector<Nucleotide>::iterator i = Sequence.begin(); i != Sequence.end(); ++i)
    {
        Nucleotide& ref = *i; //Get a reference to the object this iterator points to
        if(pos1 == ref.getPos()) //compare its base to the argument
        {
            return &ref; // Return a pointer to the correct object.
        }
    }
    return NULL; //or null if we didn't find the object we wanted
}
```